# Include Kendo React with Script Tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, kendo-ui, kendo-react-ui

I am trying to develop with Kendo React in a .NET Web Forms application.  It looks like Kendo distributes their packages as a variety of JavaScript modules -- the `dist` folder in their node packages contains the following four subfolders:

- cdn/js
- es
- npm
- systemjs

I'm sure this is relatively painless to work with in some of the newer JavaScript systems, but I do not have access to utilities such as node.js to manage modules.  I am trying to simply include a JavaScript file with a `script` tag, but so far have not had much luck.  I get the following errors when trying to include `@progress/kendo-react-common`:

- cdn/js: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined`
- es: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` (not like I expect a raw browser to understand `import` anyway)
- npm: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`
- systemjs: `Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined`

It looks like @TylerDahle has done something similar here: [How to access kendo-react widgets when accessing the react dropdowns javascript by script instead of import?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49740869/1399272) But I don't know where he gets his source from.

Is there any way to include a Kendo React script with a `script` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was posted by Progress Telerik admin Vasil [here](https://www.telerik.com/forums/include-kendo-react-with-script-tag#Law0PrJzvk-uALtKkfxbDQ):

> Hello,
>
> The correct files in this case are the JS in the CDN folders. The
>   'string' is undefined error comes from missing 'prop-types'.
>
> Let me put here some runnable html page of the Calendar that just
>   loads the required scripts.
>   https://jsbin.com/sicaquqofi/3/edit?html,output
>
> Here is the code:
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
>
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-material@latest/dist/all.css">
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.unpkg.com/prop-types@15.7.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-react-intl/dist/cdn/js/kendo-react-intl.js"></script>
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-react-dateinputs/dist/cdn/js/kendo-react-dateinputs.js"></script>
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.unpkg.com/react-transition-group@2.5.3/dist/react-transition-group.js"></script>
>   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.2/umd/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <div id="root"></div>
>     <script type="text/babel">
>       ReactDOM.render(
>         <div>
>            <KendoReactDateinputs.Calendar />
>         </div>,
>         document.getElementById('root')
>       );
>   </script>
>
>
>   </body></html>
> ```
>
> We ship kendo-react-all package. That includes all other packages.
>   https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-react-all@2.8.0/dist/cdn/js/kendo-react-all.js
>   But in this case you will need to add additional scripts for the
>   kendo-data-query and kendo-drawing. Because they are required by the
>   pdf/excel export, that are included into the all package.
>
> Here is an example with kendo-react-all cdn script loaded.
>   https://jsbin.com/cetejepamu/1/edit?html,output
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
>   <script  src="https://www.unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.2/umd/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://www.unpkg.com/react-transition-group@2.5.3/dist/react-transition-group.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://www.unpkg.com/prop-types@15.7.2/prop-types.min.js"></script>
>
>   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-material@latest/dist/all.css">
>   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@progress/kendo-drawing@1.5.10/dist/cdn/js/kendo-drawing.js">
> ```
>
> ```
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <div id="root"></div>
>     <script type="text/babel">
>
>       ReactDOM.render(
>         <div>
>         <KendoReactAll.Grid data = {[{a:'1' , b:2},{a:'3' , b:4}]} />
>         <br />
>         <KendoReactAll.Calendar />
>
>         </div>,
>         document.getElementById('root')
>       );
>   </script>
>
>
>   </body></html>
> ```
>
> Regards,
>  Vasil 
>  Progress Telerik

In particular, note the addition of the namespace before the component name (e.g. `KendoReactAll.Calendar`).

Comment: this code still gives error: Uncaught ReferenceError: KendoReactAll is not defined @Bondolin

Comment: I'm afraid that's not much for me to understand the problem, but I'll try. Can you open your browser dev tools with F12 and make sure the kendo script is indeed getting loaded?

Comment: my problem solved, i just didn't add kendoReactAll script.